# how to ensure thread safety for session attributes

Tags: java, jsp, session, jakarta-ee, servlets

I was writing j2ee code but i am facing a problem with session attribute.

Regarding ensuring of thread safety for session attributes which is being set and accessed in a servlet?
As, i know we can not implement "SingleThreadModel" because this is deprecated in java and also we can not synchronize the doXXXX() method.
I tried to use "SingleThreadModel" but it did not work. 
Then How can i ensure it?
Can i synchronize the session object for the same?

please tell me, how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a session scoped mutex. I.e. synchronize on the session, or better a use case specific object in the session.

You should keep the scope of the mutex as small as possible, as you might result in serializing your requests. I tried it once on a project of mine, where I used Spring's `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.setSynchronizeOnSession()` which simply synchronizes on the session for each request. This had a significant impact on a page which displays a list of rendered images. I could watch appearing those images sequentially.